# How to rewrite if file not found under defined folder

Tags: .htaccess

need to redirect only when file not found under given folder .

my code is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^(theme|files|images|krishna)(.*)$ Swastik/public/$1$2 [L]

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ Swastik/library/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

i have to rewrite all request to under Swastik/library/ if file not found in Swastik/public

Answer (score 0):

You can use that:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/Swastik/public%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule (.*) Swastik/public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* Swastik/library/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Did you test `RewriteCond ^Swastik/public%{REQUEST_URI} -f`?

Comment: Yes, I try to... :-) (by the way, I learn a lot from you  anubhava , thanks !)